# Crash because of onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Beginner android dev here.
I'm currently following this guide trying to create an Android app that returns the user's location.

```
package com.example.newapp;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        //show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                //check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else{
                    //can't get location
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void sendLocation(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setMessage("Your latitude is " + gps.getLatitude() + " and your longitude is " + gps.getLongitude());
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder1.create();
        alert1.show();
    }

}
```

My fragment_main.xml is like so

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.newapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="sendLocation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've commented out the onClickListener stuff and my app works fine so I know the problem is with that. I'm just not sure what about it is crashing my app on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is a tricky thing with fragments. When you add a fragment to an activity, it does not add the fragment immediately. You are adding the fragment, and then immediately trying to find a button that is inside the fragment. Unfortunately, the button isn't in your view hierarchy yet. Therefore, your btnShowLocation is null, and you get a crash on start-up when you try to set a listener on the button.

What you need to do is configure the button inside your fragment code and not your activity code. This is the logical place to do it anyway, since the button is in your fragment's layout.

Try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Notice that you have to call findViewById on rootView, NOT the fragment.
    // This is because you are in the process of telling Android about your fragment's 
    // views, but you haven't actually returned the view hierarchy yet
    Button btnShowLocation = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    //show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ...
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

You'll also have to move your gps field down from your activity to your fragment. When you use fragments, your activities tend to become very simple, and most of the logic can live in the fragment.

Comment: I've followed this and now my app launches but it crashes when I press the button.
I put inside the onClickListener "gps = new GPSTracker(gps);" as well as for the Toast.makeTest(gps, ...); as the other arguments weren't working with the code being in the fragment.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work by using getActivity() instead. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have used both

```
         setOnClickListener in class
```

and

```
         android:onClick="sendLocation"  in your xml
```

Use any one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that line:

```
android:onClick="sendLocation"
```

from the xml of yours, written inside the Button tag